# ¿Cómo encontrar el bin correspondiente a un valor en especifico dentro de un histograma?

Tags: matplotlib

tengo un histograma creado de la siguiente forma:

`n_ccdsb, bins_ccdsb, ignored1a = plt.hist(Data_hist, bins = 21, density = True)`

Data_hist es una lista de datos creada previamente. Dentro del histograma deseo encontrar a que bin corresponde un valor en específico, por ejemplo 100.

Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con `searchsorted` se puede buscar el número 100 en los bins (`bins_ccdsb`). Hay que quitar 1 del resultado para tener el índice del bin. Con este índice se puede ver su valor en la array `çn_ccdsb`. Además, con este índice se puede marcar en otro color el rectángulo que le contiene.

En el ejemplo el código define un array de números aleatorios y cree una histograma a base de ello. Después busca el número 100 en los bins y el valor correspondiente. Una cruz en amarillo marca la posición del número 100 y de su valor.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

Data_hist = np.random.normal(85, 20, 1000)

çn_ccdsb, bins_ccdsb, patches = plt.hist(Data_hist, bins=21, density=True, rwidth=0.9, color='dodgerblue')

# çn_ccdsb: valor de cada bin
# bins_ccdsb: limites de los bins (22 limites para 21 bins)

numero_buscado = 100
idx = np.searchsorted(bins_ccdsb, numero_buscado, 'left') - 1
patches[idx].set_color('crimson')
plt.axvline(numero_buscado, color='gold')
plt.axhline(çn_ccdsb[idx], color='gold')
print(f"El numero {numero_buscado} esta en bin {idx} que tiene valor {çn_ccdsb[idx]}")
plt.show()
```

Resultado:

```
El numero 100 esta en bin 12 que tiene valor 0.014118055317322149
```

[image: la histograma con las marcas]

Comment: Muchas gracias, !es justo lo que buscaba!